# Use divs like tables

Tags: css, html

I'm used to working with tables for aligning images and text, but this is not quite working with mobile devices. So I want to use CSS and DIVs instead, but I have no experience.

Basically I want to have three pictures centered, while writing text above each. They should be centered, but fill the screen that the viewer is using.

See both my CSS (a start that was not working) and the table I want it to look like below: http://beautebeaute.dk/#Hvordan

Thanks!

Comment: You should do some research, there are countless tutorials and articles on this topic on the internet.

Comment: You should start by posting some HTML

Comment: @Daniel, I did some research, but didn't quite get it right.

Comment: @Sébastien, I will do that next time. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @DanielImms just to explain - I did make the css and the div allignment, but when I post pictures in them, everything is left alligned and in one single vertical line. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can center by containing the elements in one div. make it center using margin auto and a width. then inside use sections or divs to float left and add width so that its centered. And the text is aligned using text-align.

If you are using image, dont float instead use margin:0 auto.

example http://jsfiddle.net/56Rns/3/

**html**

```
    <div class="container">
    <section>
        <h3>Title1</h3>
        <img class="pic" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2je1u2s.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus distinctio consequatur omnis quia perspiciatis accusantium recusandae. Consectetur cumque hic laboriosam autem libero officiis placeat quos perspiciatis laudantium 
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Title2</h3>
         <img class="pic" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2je1u2s.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus distinctio consequatur omnis quia perspiciatis accusantium recusandae. Consectetur cumque hic laboriosam autem libero officiis placeat quos perspiciatis laudantium 
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Title3</h3>
         <img class="pic" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/2je1u2s.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus distinctio consequatur omnis quia perspiciatis accusantium recusandae. Consectetur cumque hic laboriosam autem libero officiis placeat quos perspiciatis laudantium 
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

**css**

```
    .container{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
section{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
}
img.pic{
    width:170px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abel. When I use text only, it works as I want it to, but my problem is that whenever I use pictures everything is left alligned and in a vertical line. Do you know how to solve this?